# Tkinter image appears blank

Tags: python, tkinter

So i've been making a program for the past few days but there is this issue that I thought would be easy to fix, but turns out it wasnt so easy...

Here is my code:

```
    print("Loading...")
    from threading import *
    from tkinter import *
    import time
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Card Revealer BETA")
    root.resizable(False, False)

    image1 = PhotoImage(file="images\core\GUI.png")
    w = image1.width()
    h = image1.height()
    root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))

    panel1 = Label(root, image=image1)
    panel1.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
    Card1Image = PhotoImage(file="images\core\_blank.png")
    Card1 = Label(panel1, image=Card1Image, width=80, height=100)
    Card1.place(x=60, y=482)
    Card2Image = PhotoImage(file="images\core\_blank.png")
    Card2 = Label(panel1, image=Card2Image, width=80, height=100)
    Card2.place(x=200, y=482)
    Card3Image = PhotoImage(file="images\core\_blank.png")
    Card3 = Label(panel1, image=Card3Image, width=80, height=100)
    Card3.place(x=340, y=482)
    Card4Image = PhotoImage(file="images\core\_blank.png")
    Card4 = Label(panel1, image=Card4Image, width=80, height=100)
    Card4.place(x=490, y=482)
    Card5Image = PhotoImage(file="images\core\_blank.png")
    Card5 = Label(panel1, image=Card5Image, width=80, height=100)
    Card5.place(x=650, y=482)
    from scapy.all import *
    print("Finished loading.")
    Deck = []
    pick = None
    picked = False
    Side = ""
    def PlaceCards(cards):
        global Card1Image
        global Card2Image
        global Card3Image
        global Card4Image
        global Card5Image
        Card1Image = PhotoImage(file="images\Cards\_%s.png"%(cards[0]))
        Card2Image = PhotoImage(file="images\Cards\_%s.png"%(cards[1]))
        Card3Image = PhotoImage(file="images\Cards\_%s.png"%(cards[2]))
        Card4Image = PhotoImage(file="images\Cards\_%s.png"%(cards[3]))
        Card5Image = PhotoImage(file="images\Cards\_%s.png"%(cards[4]))

    def action(packet):
        global Deck
        global Side
        global pick
        global picked
        global switchcount
        c = 0
        try:
            if (packet[IP].src == "149.202.87.103"):

                  rawdata = packet.payload.payload.load
                  rawdata = str(rawdata)


                  if (rawdata[2:8] == "%xt%zm"):
                     if (IsOpponent(rawdata) == True):

                        if (IsDeck(rawdata) == True and picked == True):
                            rawdata = ClearFirstBit(rawdata)
                            NewCard = GetIDs(rawdata)
                            MoveUpdate(Deck[pick], NewCard)
                            print("Opponent New Deck:\n              ", Deck)
                            picked == False
                        elif (IsDeck(rawdata) == True):
                                rawdata = ClearFirstBit(rawdata)
                                Deck = GetIDs(rawdata)
                                PlaceCards(Deck)
                                picked = True
                                print("Opponent Deck:\n              ", Deck)
                        elif (IsPick(rawdata) == True):

                                pick = GetPick(rawdata)
                                print("Opponent chosen card:\n            ", Deck[pick])
                                picked = True
                  if (rawdata[2:8] == "%xt%jz"):
                      setside(rawdata[2:])
                      print("Side detected: %s"%(Side))

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    def sniffer():
        sniff(prn=action)
    sniffthread = Thread(target=sniffer)
    sniffthread.daemon = True
    sniffthread.start()
    PlaceCards([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
    root.mainloop()
```

The program is supposed to sniff your internet and try to figure out card id's in a game this is for (its a game cheat). It is able to get all the card id's and put it into an array just fine, and I made a folder with all the card images named their id so that the program can easy put your card on the gui. It is able to locate the image just fine, but it appears as a white image for some reason, so if anyone knows why this is that would be very helpful! Also, the error is NOT the gui, the gui works just fine. The issue is with the PlaceCards function

Comment: don't you get error message when you run in console/terminal/cmd.exe ? Tkinter works only with GIF image, you have to use `PIL` module to work with PNG. You have to replace image in `Label` not noly replace `PhotoImage`

Comment: in path can be `'\t"`, `"\n"`, etc. which has special meaning in text (event if it is path) so better in path use \\ or / - `"images\\Cards\\_%s.png"` or `"images/Cards/_%s.png"` - you could also print path to see if you get correct path.

Comment: to make code more readable put ALL imports at start, later ALL functions and finally `root = Tk()` and rest.

Comment: The issue with images and tkinter is explained pretty well at http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/images.html

Comment: This is way too much code. Please reduce it down to a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I solved it like this:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

pathtophoto = Image.open("images\core\GUI.png")
image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pathtophoto)
panel1 = Label(root, image=image1)
panel1.image = image1 #keep a reference
panel1.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
```

You need to make sure that the pathtophoto is a line over `root = Tk()`
I hope this helps a little.

Comment: The error was not with the gui, the gui worked just fine. The issue was with the PlaceCards function. I edited my post to make this more clear

Comment: My problem was with the line:
panel1.image = image1  # keep a reference
Don't know why this is needed? Is it perhaps a bug? Anyways this fixed my problem.